# How do I read/manipulate in JSON from an API get request?

Tags: php, json

The get request returns JSON like this where the data I want to access is in a map inside of the second 'data' variable where the keys are times and the values are temperatures, e.g. "2017-01-01 08:11:00: 4.8,".

```
{
    type: "Weather",
    name: "ISHIREMO2",
    data: {
        Temperature: {
            data: {...},
```

I am using

```
$json = file_get_contents(/*api get request here*/);
```

after this im trying to access this data using

```
foreach($json->data->Temperature->data as $key => $val) {
    /*manipulating the data here*/
}
```

but when I run it i get

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

also, when trying this with different arrays returned similar to Temperature but with a space in between, such as Wind Speed it also throws an error.

Comment: Did you [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it first?

Comment: `foreach` only takes an array or object. You need `$json = json_decode($json)`.

Comment: yeah that didnt change it

Comment: yeah sorry i missed that out of my question but i have done that and it didnt work

Comment: `print_r(json_decode($json))` and paste the result

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [type] => Weather [name] => ISHIREMO2 [data] => stdClass Object ( [Temperature] => stdClass Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( [2017-01-01 08:11:00] => 4.8 [2017-01-01 16:43:00] => 4.8 [2017-01-01 16:33:00] => 4.9 [2017-01-01 16:13:00] => 4.9 [2017-01-01 04:25:00] => 5.6 [2017-01-01 14:49:00], is much longer but not allowed that many characters